# How to run node.js, Java and PHP application on same server and same port

Tags: java, php, node.js

How to run node.js, Java and PHP application on same server and same port, I was trying to run but unable to run.

Comment: use apache as a reverse proxy

Comment: [Reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

Comment: More broadly, Don't Do This.

Answer (score 3):

You need some kind of HTTP proxy layer in front of all this, typically [Apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org) or [NGinx](https://www.nginx.com/). From there you can configure different paths to go to different applications if necessary.

The configuration directives vary considerably depending on the solution you're using, but you can have `/` go through to PHP and `/node` go through to Node, while `/java` goes somewhere else entirely. Just make sure your sub-components are using non-conflicting paths so they can all play nicely together or you'll have to do a lot of ugly URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [varnish cache](https://varnish-cache.org/) as a load director and set up different back-ends for each of those servers.  Then you could parse the incoming urls to redirect to the appropriate application server.  You can absolutely run all of those app servers on the same machine, with varnish listening on one port, and all the other services listening on other ports.  It would be easy to firewall those services from external access as well.

Running each service on different machines is also entirely possible and easy. We've used this solution numerous times in different environments because Varnish is extremely light-weight, reliable, and does not have the overhead of a web server such as Apache or nginx which, while good options, can be overkill.

You also get the added benefit of the robust caching it provides. Bonus!